# Pundit policy not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**My original problem was solved, but it has occurred again, and was not fixed using the same method**

I'm writing a simple API in Rails, using AuthLogic and Pundit for authorization, and have this error:

```
unable to find policy `SkryptPolicy` for `#<Skrypt id: 1, title: "Maths", route: "/maths/:action", script: "def main params[:one] * params[:two] if params[:ac...", user_id: nil, created_at: "2015-12-27 02:12:36", updated_at: "2015-12-27 02:12:36">`
```

I'm not authorizing `nil` like most of the other issues with this I've found, and all the relevant files exist, so I can't figure out what's going on.

I'm also working on another app using the same combination of Pundit and AuthLogic and it works perfectly, even using the same file/class names.

Here is my `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit

  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  before_filter { response.header['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' if request.format.json? }

  protected
    def current_user_session
      return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
      @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end

    def current_user
      return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
      @current_user = (current_user_session && current_user_session.user) || User.find_by(api_key: params[:api_key])
    end
end
```

`app/policies/skrypt_policy.rb`:

```
class SkryptPolicy < Struct.new(:user, :skrypt)
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      user.skrypts
    end
  end

  def index?
    not user.nil?
  end
  alias_method :create?, :index?

  def show?
    user && (skrypt.user == user)
  end
  alias_method :update?, :show?
  alias_method :destroy?, :show?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Right...

TL;DR - **restarting the server fixed it**

For some reason, restarting the `rails server` instance I had running fixed the problem. Perhaps Pundit has something in the config files that loads the policies? I don't know, because I loaded the `pundit` gem in my `Gemfile` before starting the server, but hadn't included it in my `ApplicationController`. Maybe that mucked something up.

**EDIT**

**However**, now *another* controller is having the same problem!

Okay, the second problem was solved by running `rails g pundit:install` on the command line, and then changing this line in `app/policies/skrypt_policy.rb`:

```
  class Scope < Scope
```

to this:

```
  class Scope < ApplicationPolicy::Scope
```